# VAE with mixture of gaussian prior

Tags: deep-learning, autoencoders, variational-bayes

I try to understand [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.02648.pdf) where they try to use a mixture of Gaussian as a prior, instead of the standard gaussian.
There are several things unclear to me though:

1. They say that they set $\pi_k = \frac{1}{K}$ and draw $z$ from Cat($\pi$). But later in equation 5 they parameterize $p_\beta(z_k = 1|x, w)$ by a neural network, and also condition it on the inputs. How does that fit together?
2. Also in equation 5 they calculate a KL divergence. What is this KL divergence explicitly though? How to optimize it?
3. They don't write how to optimize the $z$-prior term in equation 4. Is there a closed form solution similar to the $w$-prior term? Or how would one do that?

Answer (score 1):

1. Cat($\pi$) is the prior distribution on $z$. $p_\beta(z|x,w)$ is the variational approximation of the posterior of $z$.
2. It's the KL between the variational approximation of the posterior of $x$ (technically it's just one factor of the mean field variational approximation) and the conditional prior of $x$. These are both normal distributions, so computing the KL is easy and differentiable.
3. I believe $p(z)$ is just Cat($\pi$), so the KL can be written in closed form.

Comment: So 2. simply with the reparametrization trick? And for 3. what is the closed form of the KL?